# Como decodificar essa string em javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu recebo essa string no frontend, mas eu preciso decodificar ela.

`Tr%E1%BA%A7n_H%C6%B0ng_%C4%90%E1%BA%A1o -> Trần Hưng Đạo`

Eu não conheço nenhuma função para decodificar ela.

Comment: Apesar de estar em inglês, e claro que não é nossa obrigação e sim de quem perguntou, era de fácil entendimento e de fácil tradução, em vez de votar para fechar, poderia muito bem ter traduzido ela

Comment: Foi culpa minha, não foi por maldade. Vou cuidar na próxima. Desculpe.

Comment: Eu pensei que estava no stackoverflow em inglês, minhas desculpas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente usar a função `decodeURIComponent`:

```js
conteudo = "Tr%E1%BA%A7n_H%C6%B0ng_%C4%90%E1%BA%A1o"

console.log(decodeURIComponent(conteudo))
```

Comment: Não seria melhor usar a função [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), visto que a string não é uma URI completa e sim uma parte dela?

Comment: Funcionou, mas acho que para a vírgula e dois pontos não funcionou no caso da palavra: Music_of_Austin%2C_Texas que seria uma virgula

Comment: Com Component funcionou com as virgulas e dois pontos